# Declararle el valor de una solicitud a un array en VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

estoy tratando de declarle el valor de una respuesta de una solicitud a un array que está declarado en data, acá el código

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'Objects',
  data () {
    return {
      token: this.$q.sessionStorage.getItem('token'),
      objects: [],
      p: [
        {
          nombre: 'Andres'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    refresh (done) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.get_objects()
        done()
      }, 1000)
    },
    get_objects () {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
      var self = this
      axios.get('/Service/get_data?token=' + this.token)
        .then(function (response) {
          self.objects = response.data.resultado
        })
      console.log(self)
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.get_objects()
    console.log(this.objects)
  }
}
</script>
```

lo que quiero es tomar ese array de datos que me trae la solitud y declararsela a un array que está definido dentro de data.

Pero me está mostrando el dato mal al igualarlo fuera de la promesa, lo que me imprime el console log es :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la funcion mounted() el colocarle un console log a this.objects, la consola me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

junto con éste error que no entiendo muy bien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien me puede ayudar, se lo agradecería bastante

Comment: Edita tu respuesta y pon lo que tienes dentro de tu template

Comment: Listo amigo, ya lo he corregido la pregunta

Comment: Te falta el html

Comment: El HTML no es importante, lo único que hay en el html es una lista que no tiene funcionalidad

Comment: No puedo probar el código, no veo algún error, y aunque generalmente no es la mejor solución podrías utilizar this.$forceUpdate() después de setear el dato para ver si ha cambiado,

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es porque en tu Html no tienes declarado el key, es una suposición ya que no subiste el Html pero podría ser una solución la siguiente:

```
<div v-for="(object, idx) in objects" :key="idx">
   <!-- ... -->
</div>
```